# PHP (PCRE) Validation in a Javascript Function

Tags: javascript, php, regex, pcre

Is there an existing function (or perhaps someone wrote some existing code) to validate in a JS function that the text passed is valid PCRE? I've been Googling like crazy but the closest thing I've been able to find is just "PCRE_JAVASCRIPT_COMPAT" (which is a PCRE compatibility flag) or discussions about validating input in both PHP and Javascript.

The closest thing I've seen to Javascript REGEX validation is:

```
try {
    "".match(regex);
    return true;
} catch (e) {
    return false;
}
```

This does not take into account differences between JS (ECMA) regular expressions and PHP (PCRE) regular expressions - that's obviously an issue, but I've not found a clear discussion of the differences between the two.

Any help please?

Comment: Well, if you are working with JS, receiving an PCRE to be used with PHP, it means you will receive it in the server. You can validate there.

I don't think a valid RegExp from JS will fail when tried from PHP. Both use the same style of regexp's

Comment: Ah, that's interesting. I thought ECMA and PCRE were different styles though? And I need this to check that a supplied regex is valid **before** submitting to the server. It's client-side validation.

Comment: Yup, as you can read in http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascript.html, JS implement a *subset* of Perl-style regexps, while PCRE is mostly the whole thing.
PHP used to use "POSIX" regular expressions, in the ereg* functions. But as those are deprecated, and you should use the PCRE functions anyway, you should find no issues.

Comment: While I can use JS being a subset to reduce the validation, I still need to handle the case where someone is passing a valid PCRE pattern that is not a valid JS pattern. This is meant to validate a passed pattern to be used in PHP, after all.

Comment: Right, I was thinking the other way around. I don't think you can validate it entirely from JS, doing so would require writing your own parser. You'll have to send it to the server for validation, AJAX may be your friend in this case. You can skip the ajax validation if JS tells you the pattern is valid, at the very least.

Comment: AlvaroGMJ, could you put your AJAX solution as an actual answer? We essentially did that and while I'd add a comment about it, I'd like to give you credit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quick & Dirty AJAX code to check against PHP:

Javascript:

```
function regexValidator(value) {
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (req.status == 200 && req.responseText.length() > 0) {
            alert(req.responseText);
        }
    };
    req.open('GET', 'http://example.com/validator.php?r=' + escape(value), true);
    req.send();
}
```

PHP:

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['r'])) {
    if (preg_match(urldecode($_GET['r']), '') === FALSE) {
        echo "NOT VALID";
    } else {
        echo "VALID";
    }
}
```

Comment: I ended up with a synchronous call because I needed the method to wait for the response, but the idea was similar to what was posted.

Comment: @Paul you never *need* a synchronous call. If it looks like you do, your code needs refactoring instead.

Answer (score 2):

Interesting question. Regex baddass Steven Levithan has written a nifty [regex highlighter/colorizer](http://stevenlevithan.com/regex/colorizer/) which parses *Javascript* regular expressions and does a partial (if not complete) validation in the process. It highlights any syntax errors it finds. But regarding the PCRE regex flavor...

I have a Javascript (GitHub) project that may be of some help. Its called: [Dynamic Regex Highlighter](http://jmrware.com/articles/2010/dynregexhl/DynamicRegexHighlighter.html). It will validate PCRE syntax with regard to bracket matching for groups and character classes. However, It does not check for any other syntax requirements. If you are into regex, its probably worth a look-see anyhow. I find the tester page it to be incredibly useful when inspecting long, complex regexes (poorly) written in non-free-spacing mode. When you mouse over a bracket, the matching bracket is highlighted, and if it is a capture group, the group number is provided in a pop up tool-tip.

See: [Dynamic Regex Highlighter Tester](http://jmrware.com/articles/2010/dynregexhl/DynamicRegexHighlighterTester.html)